# Why is my C# handler code not executing even though I copied the DLL file into the bin directory and modify web.config appropriately?

Tags: asp.net

I am getting the following error:

[image]

I created a new project using the "WebSite" template and was successfully able to load the page in internet explorer 10 by accessing http://localhost:54530. Then I created another new project using the C# Class Library template which generates DLLs.  Here is how my class library looks like:

```
using System;
using System.Web;


namespace WebRequestInterceptorModule
{
public class Class1 : IHttpHandler
{


public bool IsReusable
    {
        get
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        HttpRequest request = context.Request;
        System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection nvc = request.Params;

        string test = nvc.Get(0);

        // Example #4: Append new text to an existing file.
        // The using statement automatically flushes AND CLOSES the stream and calls 
        // IDisposable.Dispose on the stream object.
        using (System.IO.StreamWriter file =
            new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\Dining Room\Documents\WriteLines2.txt", true))
        {
            file.WriteLine(test);
        }

    }
}
```

}

After building the class library solution shown above, I get two files:

```
WebRequestInterceptorModule.dll
WebRequestInterceptorModule.pdb
```

I copy both files into WebSite project's bin directory :

```
copy WebRequestInterceptorModule.dll C:\Users\Dining Room\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\WebSite1\bin

copy WebRequestInterceptorModule.pdb C:\Users\Dining Room\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\WebSite1\bin
```

Last step, I modify web.config :

```
<system.web>
<httpHandlers>
  <add verb="*" path="WebRequestInterceptorModule"
         type="WebRequestInterceptorModule.Class1" />
</httpHandlers>
</system.web>
```

The problem is when I go back to http://localhost:54530 I do not see a new file written to C:\Users\Dining Room\Documents\WriteLines2.txt

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Does the web-application actually have permission to write to that location?

Comment: I tried running the same file writing code in a windows console application (not the class library you see above) and it worked perfectly (i.e. the console application has permission to write to that location).  So the web-application should have permission too.

Comment: well, not necessarily. If they are running as different user accounts, they will have different permission sets. By default IIS will be running as a different user to a Windows Service (which will use Local System - a high privilege user)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not using the `path` directive correctly.

```
<add verb="*" path="(someURL)"
       type="WebRequestInterceptorModule.Class1, WebRequestInterceptorModule" />
```

You use the `type` field to indicate the class AND the .dll.  The `path` directive tells ASP.NET which URL binding to use.

See more here: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ConditionallyServeFilesStaticallyOrDynamicallyWithHttpHandlers.aspx

Comment: When I tried your suggestion I get the error message shown above (please see my modified post above).

Comment: for path, I tried multiple URLs like "http://localhost/*", or "/*" or "*" all of which did not work. However, when I remove the line <httpHandlers> tag the web page loads normally

Comment: I used the suggestion from this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7347897/internal-server-error-with-httphandlers-section-of-web-config and I got it to work

Comment: Ah, sorry I missed that you were on IIS 7, @user1068636. Glad you got it worked out.